# How to filter async computed data in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, filter, vuejs2

I'm using [asyncComputed](https://github.com/foxbenjaminfox/vue-async-computed) in a Vuejs 2 app, and I need to filter a list of items that I'm fetching from an api.

This is what I have so far:

```
<template>
    <div class="items">
        <input type="text" v-model="searchKey">
        <li v-for="item in items">
            <span>{{item.name}}</span>
        </li>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Items from '@/api/items';

    export default {
        name: 'items',
        data: {
            searchKey: ''
        }
        asyncComputed: {
            items: {
                async get() {
                    const items = await Items.getAll();
                    return items.data;
                },
                default: []
            }
        },
        methods: {},
        components: {}
    }
</script>
```

In this situation, **is it possible to use a filter with the pipe operator**, or do I need to create an entirely new filtered list and use that instead, like:

```
computed: {
    filteredItems: function() {
        return this.items.filter( ( item ) => item.name.toLowerCase().includes( this.searchKey.toLowerCase() );
    }
}
```

Also, if I need to create a new filtered list, how can I do that with asynchronous data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it without any of the plugins, like this:

```
<template>
    <div class="items">
        <input type="text" v-model="searchKey">
        <select v-model="filterType">
            <option disabled value="">FilterBy</option>
                <option>name</option>
                <option>id</option>
    </select>
        <li v-for="item in filteredItems">
            <span>{{item.name}}</span>
        </li>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Items from '@/api/items';

    export default {
        name: 'items',
        data: {
            searchKey: '',
            items: null,
            filterType:''
        }
        methods: {
            async fetchItems(){
                const items = await Items.getAll();
                this.items = Items.data;
            }
        },
        computed: {
            filteredItems(){
                if(this.filterType === 'name'){
                    return this.items.filter( ( item ) => item.name.toLowerCase().includes( this.searchKey.toLowerCase() );
                }

                if(this.filterType === 'id'){
                    return this.items.filter( ( item ) => item.id.includes( this.searchKey );
                }

                if(!this.filterType){
                    return this.items;
                }
            }
        },
        created(){
            this.fetchItems();
        }
    }
</script>
```

You can even use a `select` input to select the criteria by which the list is to be filtered, in this case by `id` or by `name`.